# Python: PackageNotFoundError No package metadata was found for <myproject>

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.12

I have an existing python project and trying to debug in via
Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

Therefore I have the following launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: myproject",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "E:\\<path>\\__main__.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${cwd}" },
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "--config=E:\\<path>\\config.yaml"
            ],

        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately it runs up to one excpetion:

> Exception has occurred: PackageNotFoundError No package metadata was
> found for myproject

> importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found
> for myproject

I already tried

> pip install importlib.metadata

But it doesn't help.

The lines of code that are running the exception are in the return:

> import atexit, copy, getopt, importlib.metadata, json, logging, os,
> re, signal, shutil, sys, textwrap, time, urllib
>
> . . .
> return importlib.metadata.version(**package**)

Using the interpreter:
[image]

Anyone could help how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After additional research it was just an only the following command, that helped:

```
pip install -e .
```

If someone has the same issue (the current project wasn't installed)